# How to add a package to official raspbian repositories?

Tags: raspbian, apt, packages

How to add a package to official raspbian repositories ?

Debian has a very extensive guide into the matter :
https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/distribute-deb/distribute-deb.html#adding-packages-to-debian

But what about raspbian ?

Will it "automagically" mirror every package present in debian repos ?

Comment: Would a answer on how to make your own be ok?

Comment: Make my own "repo" ? No, I know how to do it. My question is really about  getting my package in http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ probably in the `contrib` section

Comment: Yeah sorry 'how to make your own "repo"' :) . To add stuff to the offical repos think you need to go a process through which you show you are trustworthy and exist etc, then you can become a [debian maintainer](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianMaintainer) or  [debian developer/member](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianDeveloper). You may need a existing debian dev to advocate you, which is why it is easier to set up your own repo/PPA/whatever.

Comment: As said in my question, I've already found out the process for debian my question is for raspbian, since I suppose there might be ARM compatibility issues / advanced cross compilation requirements. I couldn't find a simple and clear statement into the matter

Comment: I was wondering if you've gotten onto IRC and connected to the Raspbian IRC channel on Freenode. That's where the devs for Raspbian hang out with the community, and I have a feeling you're more likely to get a direct answer to your question there than here.

Comment: No, but that seems a good idea. I'll give it a try. Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with the Raspberry Pi. Its just about package system for an OS. Please go and try on Ubuntu Stack for a better answer and more attention

Comment: @ppumkin, and they would tell him to come back here as raspbian is not ubuntu. The folks at U&L would be welcoming but this really is rpi specific.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends.

If the program has no dependencies on Pi specific libraries then getting it into Debian is the way to go. It should then be pulled in from there and built by our autobuilders.

If it does depend on Pi specific libraries then you will need to prepare suitable packages and file a bug report with us and I will try to take a look. If adding pi-specific functionality to an existing program then it must be done as an additional package with new source/binary names, NOT a replacement for a package imported from Debian.

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks for the work you're doing, thanks for droping by ;), thanks for the answer. Btw you should add a line about it on the main site's FAQ / Repository section. Regards